# Чем профилировать nodejs для поиска утечки памяти?

Tags: node.js, профилирование

Запускается приложение так:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 node dist/index.js
```

В течении дня при активной работе растет потребление оперативной памяти до 8gb.

С помощью каких инструментов можно отследить где конкретно происходит повышенное потребление памяти? Желательно чтобы выводился древовидный список по функциям, переменным и файлам, которые потребляют больше всех памяти. Ну и информация по утечкам.

Comment: `node --trace_gc app.js & node-inspector`  https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0oZa64SB2wM